# Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Prove: $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
>  e^{-nx^2}dx$ for every natural number

I tried a lot of things, I think induction is the way to go here but I couldn't really get anywhere after the initial stage.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Change of variable $x=\sqrt{n}u$ in the first integral.

Answer (score 5):

By the change of variable $x=\sqrt{n}\:u$, giving $\,dx=\sqrt{n}\:du$, then you get

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\large-x^2}dx=\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
>  e^{\large-nu^2}du,
> $$

as announced.